# Noise Figure And Amplifier Equation

Tags: noise

I'm trying to understand how a particular equation works.  The scenario is: there is a load of some resistance connected onto an amplifier with some noise figure.

The thermal noise of the load alone is:
$$
\langle i_{th}^2 \rangle = 4kTB/R
$$
but since there is an amplifier before it, the noise at the input of the amplifier is
$$
\langle i_{th}^2 \rangle = 4kTBF/R.
$$

I know that
$$
F = \frac{SNR_{in}}{SNR_{out}} = \frac{S_i}{S_o} \frac{N_o}{N_i} = \frac{1}{G} \frac{N_o}{N_i}
$$
and I'm not seeing why multiplying $4kTB/R$ by $F$ is going to find the noise at the input of the amplifier.

Advice much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MattL. Ah okay, yes I wasn't sure where to post it.  It's not really DSP, but it's also not really electronics, but at the same time, it's sort of both of them!
---
I think the answer might be because when compared to an ideal amplifier (no noise added, just signal gain), the $G$ well end up cancelling and it'll turn out that the noise increase by a factor of $F$.